# Afraid I lost my XMR, balance not updating. Please help

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, transaction-data, full-node, balance

I'm running Oxygen Orion v0.17.1.9 on Tails/a Ledger device. I set it up as a full node originally. My daemon syncs and runs just fine, as far as I can tell. When connected to remote node, my wallet syncs up as per the height in the bottom left, but two transactions that somehow were sent to myself instead of the address I typed in have not shown up. One transaction says it is "received", and it was sent to my "second account", yet my balance does not show it. I try to type status in the log to see what the readout says, and I get the error I stated in the title (Couldn't connect to Daemon 127.0.0.1:18081).

I attempted to run in local  node mode, as I have the blockchain downloaded, but I get the same error over and over, and then I get a "general SOCKS server failure" error over and over in my daemon.
I am afraid that I have lost the XMR or something? I'm somewhat new to all of this. I was hesitant to do a wallet refresh because one transaction that was somehow sent to me is in limbo right now. I attempted to send funds to an address, double checked that I had the right one pasted in, and I came back later to see it went to me instead. I really have no idea what's going on and would appreciate any help in getting my wallet to properly connect to my Daemon and hopefully get the funds that are in limbo right now.

Should I redownload the blockchain? Refresh the wallet? I'm lost here...

I can provide any more information if more is necessary.

Comment: You should have the 25 word seed.  On a non tails machine create a wallet and sync to a remote node.  If that works, use the seed to recreate your tails wallet and see that happens.

Comment: I attempted to sync to a remote note but it wouldnt connect? I used 127.0.0.1 and port 17600 and it wouldnt connect for me

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not a remote connection.  That is the IP address of the machine your are on. (Every PC uses that as the loopback/localhost address). Where did you get that port 17600?  You can do a 'netstat -plant' and see what ports are open/listening/connected on the local machine. Or nmap -p- <remote IP> for a LAN or internet node machine